# getting an array in <td> one after another

Tags: php, arrays

i do have a little problem in creating table from 2-dimentional array.

I am getting dynamic array from one page like,

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1374
        [id] => 1374 )
        [1] => 223
        [version_id] => 223

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1540
        [id] => 1540)
        [1] => 224
        [version_id] => 224

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1541
        [id] => 1541)
        [1] => 225
        [version_id] => 225
)
```

I want data in table like,

[image: Required]

Comment: please provide any foreach or while looping method

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: I have tried : 
    foreach($get_data_as_array as $value) {

($value[id]);

}

Comment: sorry, but i also want one more thing **field_name** (as in my original array in starting of all values of all rows)

Comment: please see my updated image. maybe i was not able to clearly show what i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by html structure

"row" `<tr>` must render first then "column" `<td>`

it would be easier to render by each row

### UPDATES

here is exactly what you want..

### 3rd Edited

defined sample $data

```
$data = array(
        array(
            0 => 1374,
            'id' => 1374,
            1 => 223,
            'version_id' => 223
        ),
        array(
            0 => 1540,
            'id' => 1540,
            1 => 224,
            'version_id' => 224
        ),
        array(
            0 => 1541,
            'id' => 1541,
            1 => 225,
            'version_id' => 225
        )
    );
```

assumes you knows fields info or retrieve by mysql_field_name

```
    $fields = array('id', 'version_id'); 
    echo '<table class="spec">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>name</th>';

for ($n = 0; $n < sizeof($data); $n++) {
    echo '
            <th>array_data-' . $n . '</th>';
}

echo '
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>';

for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($fields); $i++) {
    echo '<tr>
            <td>' . $fields[$i] . '</td>';

    foreach ($data as $row) {
        echo '<td>' . $row[$i] . '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}

echo '</tbody>
    </table>';
```

Comment: it's giving error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING" on first foreach line

Comment: ok, see updates above. IMHO i'd prefer to insert `<?php //shortcode ?>` into HTML template (the View in MVC) like CI, cakephp or smarty template.

Comment: please see my updated image. maybe i was not able to clearly show what i want

Comment: oops, typo mistake `foreach($data as $row)`

Comment: Thank you very much **ai.farfa**

Answer (score 1):

```
$multidim_arr = array
(
 array
    ( 
        0 => 1374,
        1 => 223
),
array
    (
        0 => 1540,
        1 => 224
),
array
    (
        0 => 1541,
        1 => 225
)
);
$n = count($multidim_arr);
$z = count($multidim_arr[$n-1]);
echo "<table>";
for($j = 0; $j<$z;$j++) {
  echo "<tr>";
  for($i = 0; $i<$n; $i++) {
    echo "<td>".$multidim_arr[$i][$j]."</td>";
  }
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

first of all do PDO::FETCH_NUM in PDO not PDO::FETCH_BOTH
check http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

regards

@edit or with keys:

```
<?php

$multidim_arr = array
(
 array
    ( 
        'id' => 1374,
        'version_id' => 223
),
array
    (
        'id' => 1540,
        'version_id' => 224
),
array
    (
        'id' => 1541,
        'version_id' => 225
)
);
$n = count($multidim_arr);
$z = count($multidim_arr[$n-1]);
$keys = array_keys($multidim_arr[$n-1]);
echo "<table>";
for($j = 0; $j<$z;$j++) {
  echo "<tr>";
  for($i = 0; $i<$n; $i++) {
    echo "<td>key: ".$keys[$j]." and value: ".$multidim_arr[$i][$keys[$j]]."</td>";
  }
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

@edit another example

```
<?php

$multidim_arr = array
(
 array
    ( 
    0 => 1374,
        'id' => 1374,
    1 => 223,
        'version_id' => 223
),
array
    (
    0 => 1540,
        'id' => 1540,
        1 => 224,
        'version_id' => 224
),
array
    (
    0 => 1541,
        'id' => 1541,
        1 => 225,
        'version_id' => 225
)
);
$n = count($multidim_arr);
$z = count($multidim_arr[$n-1])/2;
$keys = array('id', 'version_id');
echo "<table>";
for($j = 0; $j<$z;$j++) {
  echo "<tr>";
  for($i = 0; $i<$n; $i++) {
    echo "<td>key: ".$keys[$j]." and value: ".$multidim_arr[$i][$keys[$j]]."</td>";
  }
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

but here you have to knows the keys.

Comment: one more thing i want to ask, if you have little extra time.
I also want to display row names like **'id'**, which is there in arrays infront of each row.

Comment: like **'id'** and **version_id**, which is there in arrays in front of each row, which is there in my original array.

Comment: but that is printing both, **key: 0 and value: 1374** and after that **key: id and value: 1374**

Comment: hi, but i can't edit the array in my file, this is the array i am getting after unserialize function.

Comment: Sorry, but I want to print the field_name one time in <td> and then the records, just like the comparison between 3 items.

Answer (score 0):

//haven't tested but should be good ..

```
$count_multi = count($multidim_arr);
echo '<table border="1"><tbody><tr>';
for($i=0;$i<$count_multi;$i++)
{
   $subarr = $multidim_arr[$i];
   echo '<td>Content at index'.$i.' of multi-dimensional array <br />'.$subarr['id'].'</td>';
}
echo '</tr></tbody></table>';
```

Comment: not worked. only <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr> returned in source

Comment: I've tested and it works as you asked for .. post your code here to look at.

Comment: please see my updated image. maybe i was not able to clearly show what i want